# Exmark side bagger pin placement

Tags: untagged

[image]I have a 52” exmark and a 60 inch , the pin on thsi bagger system is only set for the 52 as shown in the photo, I need the pin to go into the slot right below it but the smaller pin holding the larger pin doesn’t accept an Allen wrench so I don’t know how to take it off [image]

Comment: Any chance the manufacturer can help you out with the info?

Answer (score 2):

[image: Detail of pin]

The slight gap at 2 O'Clock or so suggests that this is a **spring pin** or **roll pin**, not a stripped out threaded fastener.

Typically there will be a hole on the other side of the tube and you can just drive it through with a punch. Verify the hole on the other side by feel since you probably can't see it before pounding on it. Otherwise you grab with a pair of pliers and pull, but there's not a lot there to grab.

If this would be changed only rarely that may be original. There are multiple other pin designs that are more suited to regular changes.

Comment: Thanks for this information, I am just worried that when I pull this out that I won’t be able to reinstall it because it looks like it works by expanding once inside the opening. Which causes it to lock into place. How would I go about expanding it in the opening once I get it out of the current one ?

Comment: The ends are slightly tapered, and it doesn't expand all that much. The tapered end fits the hole, and driving it in compresses it.